# Manage Camera from External Button

Tags: python, opencv, camera

i'm writing some code in python and opencv to use a microscope which has a potentiometer and a button, to manage the luminosity and to capture an image.

Everything works well in capturing an image via software, but i would capture an image simply pushing the button on the microscope.

i'm trying to find a way to exploring raw data incoming from usb's connection but i'm becoming crazy...

is there a simple way using opencv libraries to capture an image in this way?

here is my little size of code:

```
vc = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
cv.NamedWindow("LIVE")

while True:
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(vc)
    cv.ShowImage("LIVE", frame)

    key = cv.WaitKey(20)

    if key == (button pressed on the camera): ??????????
         cv.SaveImage('img\\image.png'.format(1),frame)

    if key == 27:
         cv.DestroyWindow("LIVE")
```

Thank you so much for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't handle key press events from such device. So, the solution of your problem is impossible by means of OpenCV only

Comment: well, this is a bad news! ....
and can i use something to "listen" the incoming stream from usb ?